# Video Player Does Have control ⁃ Quality Option(360p, 720p, 1080p) ⁃ Speed option(2x, 3x, 4x)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I find any dependency play video with Quality Option(360p, 720p, 1080p) ⁃ Speed option(2x, 3x, 4x), and auto play next video..

my video link network or file.